# \Drupal::request() vs $request_stack->getCurrentRequest()

Tags: 8

These seem to return the same thing:

`\Drupal::request()`

`$request_stack->getCurrentRequest()`

Which is the preferred way to get the current request and why? Is one of these to be deprecated? Any other advantages/disadvantages?

Thanks!

Comment: What context are you calling it in? Generally speaking if your context supports dependency injection, you would inject the request stack service and use it the latter way (better for testability). If you're in procedural code, e.g. a hook, you would use the former

Comment: Thanks, @Clive ... it is in a service that I didn't originally write and I had seen the other way from more time in hooks, but that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How to get the current request object:

**Procedural**

In procedural code get the request from the static wrapper `\Drupal`:

```
$request = \Drupal::request();
```

**Service**

In a service get the current request from the injected argument `@request_stack`:

The `module_name/module_name.services.yml` file :

```
services:
  custom.service:
    class: Drupal\module_name\Service\CustomService
    arguments:
      - '@request_stack'
```

The `module_name/src/Service/CustomService.php` file :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

/** @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack */
protected $requestStack;

class customService
{
  public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack) {
    $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
  }

  public function doSomething() {
    // use $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()
  }
}
```

**Controller**

In a controller you can pull the request from the route argument stack by including a typed request parameter. An example from `UserController`:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

  public function resetPass(Request $request, $uid, $timestamp, $hash) {          
    // use $request
  }
```

It's not necessary to define the route parameter in the route definition. The request is always available.

**Form**

In a form method get the request from `getRequest()`:

```
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    ...
  }
```

Don't use the injected requestStack property directly, because it is not available for all Form API callbacks.

Comment: Thanks! ... it is in a service that I didn't originally write and I had seen the other way from more time spent in hooks, but that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: How does a service get the injected request stack?

Comment: @joachim, the service needs `@request_stack` as argument. You find examples in core.services.yml.

Comment: @4k4 Could you give us an example scenario of when the requestStack wouldn't be available if injected directly?

Comment: @HeitorAlthmann, if injected directly it would be available, but you can't be sure it is when using the form class in Form API. `$request = $this->getRequest()` gets the request from the injected service, but has a fallback in case it is not available.